# Wrapping a releaseable object into a smart pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

As far as I understand the smart pointers, they are there to avoid memory leaks among other things. However there are often objects which also need to be released, but not by `free` or `delete`. Is there some generic way of using such pointers with a template?

As an example `FILE` comes to mind, which should use `fclose` when done. Of course there are other kind of pointers with unique release functions of their own. So do I have to implement seperate wrappers to account for their individual release method, or is there some better way to do this?

Something that may be used like this:

```
smart_ptr<FILE, fclose> fl = fopen();
smart_ptr<IStream, T->Release> pFileStream = SHCreateStreamOnFile(...);
```

Comment: Yes, smart pointers in the standard library accept custom release functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, you can provide your custom deleter. The deleter for a `unique_ptr` is passed as a template parameter, and

> Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an argument of type `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`

For the `shated_ptr`, the deleter should be provided as the constructor parameter.

```
class Foo
{

};

class Deleter
{
public:
    void operator()(Foo *)
    {
        std::cout << "deleter";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, Deleter> ptr(new Foo());
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr1(new Foo(),
                             [](Foo*){std::cout << "deleter for shared_ptr";}
                             );
}
```

You have to be careful not to cause memory leaks, though.

Comment: But this still means that I have to write an individual deleter for each type of object, right?

Comment: @Devolus, yes, for each type of object that needs specific treatment.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping to get around this by maybe using a clever template or such by providing the method and not have to worry about this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Both `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` provide that facility.

---

For `shared_ptr`, the constructor is a template:

> An optional deleter d can be supplied that is later used to destroy the object when no shared_ptr objects own it. By default, a delete-expression for type Y is used as the deleter.

In this case, the deleter can be any callable, *copy-constructible* **value**, which get type-erased to the callable.

For `unique_ptr`, the type of the deleter is a type parameter of the pointer itself:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
> class unique_ptr;
```

There's no erasure in this case, and the deleter provided to the c-tor or the reset actually matches the deleter type.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct both `shared_ptr` (signature #3 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)) and `unique_ptr` (signature #2 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) with custom deleters.

```
using T = ...;
auto deleter = [](T* x) { delete x; };

// different deleter - different unique_ptr type
// deleter is stored inline
auto x = std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)>(new T(...), deleter);

// same shared_ptr<T> type regardless of the deleter type,
// deleter is stored in the "shared state"
auto y = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...), deleter);
```

Note, `make_shared()` cannot be used to construct a `shared_ptr` with custom deleter.